# how can i achieve this ? I'm trying to have an Input that will print out all the numbers in sequential order using python

Tags: python

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ9Ki.jpg)This is what I want my output to be.

What I have now.

```
rows = int(input("Please Enter a Number  : "))

for I in range(1, rows + 1):

    for j in range(1, I + 1):

        print('*', end = '  ')

    print()
```

But This is what I want my output to be

```
Enter any number : 21
Output
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21
```

Right Angle triangle output thing.

Its been driving me nuts.
Please help :)
Thanks in anticipation

Comment: So if i understood you want to print all the numbers between 1 and the input number ?

Comment: I want user to enter an input and the numbers will be printed in sequential order. Like the image I uploaded as desired output.

Comment: @Yasha_ops . Yes

Comment: Note: if you don't use the variable in the loop, you can write `for _ in ...: ...`

Comment: @codingembryo Did the answer helped you ? If so please consider mark your question as solved

Comment: This is what I have.

Please Enter a Number  : 30
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36

It is printing more than the input. I want it stop at the number inputted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the triangle part, the first step is to print all the numbers:

```py
rows = int(input("Please Enter a Number  : "))
for num in range(1, rows + 1):
  print(num, end=" ")
```

From there we want to add an `if` to also print a new line if our number is

- equal to 'rows', or
- the number we expect to be at the end of the current level

Since the number of items in each row is an arithmetic progression (i.e. each level is +1 longer than the level above it) we can calculate the number at the end of each level using the formula for summing an arithmetic progression:

```py
number_at_end_of_level = level * (level + 1) / 2
```

The simple explanation for this formula is that you're finding the average number of items in each level by averaging the first and last level `average = (level + 1) / 2`. Because we know the average, we can then multiply that by the number of levels to get the total.

So putting it all together the solution is:

```py
rows = int(input("Please Enter a Number  : "))
level = 1
for num in range(1, rows + 1):
  print(num, end=" ")
  number_at_end_of_level = level * (level + 1) / 2
  if num == number_at_end_of_level or num == rows:
    level += 1
    print()
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to do the calculation, you can just count how many items you've printed in the current level and print a new line when that count is equal to the current level number:

```py
rows = int(input("Please Enter a Number  : "))
level = 1
current_level_count = 0
for num in range(1, rows + 1):
  print(num, end=" ")
  current_level_count += 1
  if current_level_count == level or num == rows:
    level += 1
    current_level_count = 0
    print()
```

Comment: Thank you @ Rob Croft. This really solves the whole headache and explains the answer to  my question perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Hellor, here's your solution for your problem

```py
rows = int(input("Please Enter a Number  : "))
count = 1
number = 1
while number <= rows:
    for i in range(count):
        print(number, end=" ")
        number += 1
    count += 1
    print("\n", end="")
```

Since you always need to add one number per line
you need a variable to store the number of numbers
to print (Here `count`).
You also need a variable to count the current number
that you increment for each iteration of `count`
(here `number`) and you stop only when the current
number is greater then the input (Here `rows`)

Comment: This would be improved with elaboration. _Why_ is this the answer?